# Excel Graph - 2 Line chart / Each line representing it's own data set

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010, pivot-table, vba

I have tried multiple ways to create this graph but I can not. If I place the data into a pivot table, it will not allow me to create the graph (error message is that I can not create a graph from a scatter chart). I am placing it in a pivot table to group the data for both columns to help organize the chart (the dates are formatted 1/1/2015 so I am trying to group all dates into months).

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

I have two columns. Column A and Column B.

**Column A / 319 rows** - Data consists of dates ranging from every month in the year 2015

**Column B / 109 rows** - Data consists of dates ranging from every month in the year 2016

I am trying to create a line graph that shows the following:

**Two lines**, one representing **2015** and one **2016**.

The **x-axis** should display the **months** throughout a year.
The **y-axis** should display numbers (representing # of times data shows up in that month).

Am I using a wrong chart? Am I not setting up my data correctly?

Currently, in row **A1** and **B1** are the years, so **2015** in **A1** and **2016** in **B1**. Every row below that has random dates.

Basically each of these dates represents a open ticket so I am trying to find out how many tickets were opened in each month.

Photos due to request:

I can get a single line, but not with two sets of data.

[image]

two sets of data:

[image]

Moving dates into one column, still one line:

[image]

@SeanC  - The data is not accurate. Also, there are no dates for 2016 from July-Dec. Also, it shows 2 dates for June 2016 but there are more. 2015 looks more accurate but not 2016.

[image]

@SeanC - Removed the 2016 total, same issue

[image]

Adding more evidence here (Lastest Date in Column B is June 28 and it also has 13 dates June - If you notice, the pivot table shows 2 dates for June and also dates for months that don't even exist in Column B):

[image]

Comment: can you upload a screenshot with examples from both columns ? just a sample of the data you have

Comment: You can use PIVOT and create a chart, but you will need to modify your data structure. You need all of your data, all the dates in column A and B to be in Column A (put the values from Column B under the ones in Column A, and Cell A1 should be Date.  Then you can create a PIVOT, and group the results by Year and Month. I hope I am being clear...

Comment: @ShaiRado I added a screenshot.

Comment: @ShaiRado I followed your suggestion but there is still only one line of data. I will post picture in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. What you may not realize is that Excel will accept the same field in value and in a row/column/filter

Put column A in Row Labels, then put columns A and B in Values.

Group column A by months (leave out the years) and you will end up with the counts you require.

Comment: Hi Sean, check my original post for the most recent picture. I followed your instructions but it seems my data is not accurate.

Comment: remove 2015 or 2016 from the row labels - it seems to be trying to subtotal rather than grouping

Comment: Removed 2016 (tried doing it both ways), date is still not accurate for 2016. @SeanC

Comment: Removed 2016 (tried doing it both ways), date is still not accurate for 2016

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I almost found my answer by placing the year value to the legend.

[image]

The blue line is accurate but not the red.

Comment: see my answer and screen-shot above, I think somehow the red plotted series in chart is reading the data from the "Grand Total" column in the PIVOT table.

Answer (score 0):

I Think in your latest screen-shot you plotted the Grand Total series instead of 2016 (or there is some mix-up in the Data).

Please see attached screen-shot of the table and chart I got when putting all the dates in a single column (I only typed in a part of your data, just to check it's running OK)

Excuse my chart, going right-to-left, some Hebrew settings my wife did on the PC at home :)

[image]